# Changing chart axis group removes formatting

Tags: vba, excel, charts, formatting

I'm creating a workbook that will be used as a template for creating graphs. The units used are 'ppm' and 'ppb' and will be on two vertical axes.

The below code is to run when the user sets which axis to use for a dataset. It works, but all formatting is removed from the secondary axis, as well as the axis title. Is there a way I can retain this formatting?

```
Sub AxisChange()
Dim sp As Worksheet
Set sp = Worksheets("Setup Page")
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("P1")
Dim cht As ChartObject

If sp.Cells(22, 4).Value = ("ppm") Then
     For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
     cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 2
     Next cht
Else
     For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
     cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
     Next cht
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How many series are in each chart? How many on each axis (axis group) of each group? To retain the secondary axis, make sure there is at least one series left on this axis after the code runs. It can be a dummy series with no visible points.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Each chart will have 8 series and there could be any number on either axis. I have since found that if I manually deselect one series from the secondary axis, it removes all series from the axis and resets the formatting. This behavior doesn't seem normal and is possibly the cause of this issue. After deleting and rebuilding the charts, the secondary axis remains with a dummy series in place as you suggested.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. How many series were on the secondary axis, and how are you deselecting just one series from the secondary axis?

Comment: There were four series on the secondary axis. I right clicked>Change Chart Type and used the secondary axis tick boxes to deselect. All series would deselect at once, thus removing the axis and formatting. If I were to click ok, I could not then reopen the Change Chart Type window. After saving and reopening the file Excel says it found a problem and then deletes the affected charts.

Comment: After making new charts, they behave as expected but after running the above code a few times the problems can resurface. Keeping a dummy series on the secondary axis, even if hidden, seems to stop the problem occurring. Note the code above has changed, the If statement has been duplicated for all 8 series.